# Jnr jQuery - Whats wrong with this syntax?

Tags: jquery

Early days of tryng to learn jQuery, what am I doing wrong below?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(#hide-employee).click(function(){
    alert("link was clicked.");
  });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: You missing quotes `$("#hide-employee")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide-employee").click(function(){
    alert("link was clicked.");
  });
});
```

The Quotes are missing in your selector. But this answer is quite obvious, 5 seconds of research would have helped you, too.

**EDIT:**

The Quotes are neccessary because they get handled like text in a query selector. Even in plain JavaScript you use quotes for this, i.e.: `document.getElementById("test");`

Comment: Care to explain what the quotes do? Currently you give him no clue on why it was wrong, only on how to fix it.

Comment: Sorry @hallleron, been starting and researching for ages was being blind after too long in front of screen. Thanks to Stephan & Edwin though.

Comment: No problem, I added an explanation now.

Answer (score 1):

You have missing quotes near  $(#hide-employee), #hide-employee is supposed to be a string and is being treated as a comment. There by your are to add quotes surrounding #hide-employee to get  $("#hide-employee");

More info of javascript or query types
developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structu‌​res

Error near  "$(#hide-employee)", missing quotes

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(#hide-employee).click(function(){
    alert("link was clicked.");
  });
});
```

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide-employee").click(function(){
    alert("link was clicked.");
  });
});
```

Comment: Care to explain what the quotes do? Currently you give him no clue on why it was wrong, only on how to fix it.

Comment: It is a type issue, anything in quotes is treated as a text, whilst without quotes it is treated as a variable name.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures

Comment: So add it to your answer ;-)